# WrapPanel displaying ListView is not virtualizing

Tags: wpf, listview, virtualization

I tested many variations of virtualization, and yet did not get a working version. I checked the virtualization through Snoop, where virtualized visual tree contained only the displayed items and non-virtualized contained all items.

the ItemsSource (NumberList) contains 500 items (integers 1..500).
the following version is virtualized:

```
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="lbDefault" Margin="15,10" Width="300" Height="200"
     ItemsSource="{Binding NumberList}"
     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

The following code is not working:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Name="lbDefault" Margin="15,10" Width="300" Height="200"
     ItemsSource="{Binding NumberList}"
     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
     VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
     ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Shai

Comment: There is no, built in, version of `WrapPanel` that supports virtualization as there is for `StackPanel` and `VirtualizingStackPanel`. Basically when you use `WrapPanel` virtualization is off. You can try with [`VirtualizingWrapPanel`](https://virtualwrappanel.codeplex.com/) but it's not perfect and has few issues

Answer (score 0):

have a look [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/309151/Wrap-Panel-Virtualization) and [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75847/Virtualizing-WrapPanel), tell you about how to get a Virtualizing Wrap Panel.

Comment: let me know if you need any help using these.

Comment: Are the solutions you suggested robust and tseted, or have any issues?

Comment: Are the solutions you suggested robust and tseted, or have any issues?

Comment: hahahaha, you don't have to copy paste them, take the idea and implement and if you read the link thoroughly you will know what state they are .. Guess they work fine for most of us, depending on how you use the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my VirtualizingWrapPanel if you still haven't found a solution: https://github.com/Thomas-Hoffmann/HorizontalVirtualizingWrapPanel